# Spring Integration - Which Deserializer to use for an endless stream of bytes with only a start-byte (being part of the message)

Tags: java, spring-integration

We are trying to read enOcean data from TCP.

The protocol description for enOcean ESP3-Messages says:

As soon as a Sync.-Byte (value 0x55) is identified, the subsequent 4 byte-Header is compared with the corresponding CRC8H value.
If the result is a match the Sync.-Byte is correct. Consequently, the ESP3 packet is detected properly and the subsequent data will be passed.
If the Header does not match the CRC8H, the value 0x55 does not correspond to a Sync.-Byte. The next 0x55 within the data stream is picked and the verification is repeated.

Until now we used a device (client) that automatically closes the connection to our server after the end of a number of messages coming within a very small timeframe (some milliseconds). Therefore we were able to use a simple ByteArrayRawSerializer. Whenever the connection was closed we got the byte array, read the data, found all the sync-Bytes and were able to interpret the messages.

Now there is a new device that is holding the connection for a very long time (several minutes), so we somehow need another way to read the data from the stream. Because there is no End-of-Message-Byte and the SyncByte 0x55 is part of the message and a ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer doesn't suit us either we wonder what we could use:

Is there any Deserializer usable for our scenario? Is it possible to writer our own Deserializer (in this specific scenario)? Or is there another (simpler) way we should follow? Maybe use an Interceptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to write a custom deserializer.